# Generic ObservableCollection for any of my entities

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, observablecollection

I use `Entity Framework` to access my data on `SQL Server` and I need to display data from my SQL tables in `WPF DataGrid`. I know how to do that for any of my entities: I create a `View` with `DataGrid`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Rows}" SelectedItem="{Binding Row}" />
```

and `ViewModel` with `ObservableCollection<PERSONS>` as a public property:

```
public class DictionaryViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<PERSONS> rows;
    public ObservableCollection<PERSONS> Rows
    {
         get
         {
              return rows;
         }
         set
         {
              rows = value;
              RaisePropertyChanged("Rows");
         }
    }

    public DictionaryViewModel()
    {
        Rows = new ObservableCollection<PERSONS>(myDataContext.PERSONS);
    }
}
```

My question is **how I do that for an *arbitrary* entity**? Is there generic type for entities? It would be nice to write something like this:

```
public class DictionaryViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<GenericType> rows;
    public ObservableCollection<GenericType> Rows
    {
         get
         {
              return rows;
         }
         set
         {
              rows = value;
              RaisePropertyChanged("Rows");
         }
    }

    public DictionaryViewModel(GenericType type)
    {
        Rows = new ObservableCollection<type>(...);
    }
}
```

I really do not want to create a separate `ViewModel` for each entity I have.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please please confirm whether you do not want to create separate ViewModel or ObservableCollection for each entity?

Comment: `ViewModel` as I mentioned in my question. I'd like to get one `ViewModel` which takes entity as a parameter

Comment: Well im editing my answer..please wait for 2 mints

Comment: Yes now you can check my answer.. I have edited it according to your need.

Comment: do you want one instance of your concrete `ViewModel` where you can fill in and **mix** any type? or x-instances where each is strongly typed?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair  I want to fill `Rows` by `PERSONS` or `DEPARTMENTS`. E.g. user click on a button "Manage users". `DictionaryView` is about to open, where `DataGrid` is filled by `PERSONS`. The same thing with `DEPARTMENTS`. I do not want to mix them, that's unnatural :)

Comment: good question , exactly what im facing right now !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simply introduce a generic-parameter to your class?

```
public class DictionaryViewModel<T> : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> _rows;
    public ObservableCollection<T> Rows
    {
         get
         {
              return _rows;
         }
         set
         {
              _rows = value;
              RaisePropertyChanged("Rows");
         }
    }
}
```

You just have to create 2 instances (one for `Person`, one for `Department`) and implement a gateway-logic to bind the correct source.

edit:
If you want to use one instance with different types ... forget about it! introduce a base-class for `Person` and `Department` where you define the common properties and use this new type as your generic-constraint.

Comment: Well, that seems to what I need. I'll try that later and let you know a result. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do that. You just need to use Object in place of Generic Type. Your code may look like below

```
public class ViewModelBase
{
    // base class code
}

public class DictionaryViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public DictionaryViewModel()
    {
        Rows = new ObservableCollection<Object>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Object> rows;
    public ObservableCollection<Object> Rows
    {   
        get
        {
            return rows;
        }
        set
        {
            rows = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Rows");
        }
    }
}
```

Now Rows can hold any arbitrary entity.

Comment: I am not sure if this is what the OP wants... if you are going for `object`, you can add anything to the collection and even mix `int` with `string` (... and so on) - the question is a bit unclear to me...

Comment: Now `Rows` holds a set of `objects`, that's not what I need, actually. But thanks for helping

Comment: What is the reason of using generic with constant type parameter in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a generic `ObservableCollection<T>`.

**[`ObservableCollection<T> Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)**

```
public class DictionaryViewModel<T> : ViewModelBase
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> rows;
    public ObservableCollection<T> Rows
    {
         get
         {
              return rows;
         }
         set
         {
              rows = value;
              RaisePropertyChanged("Rows");
         }
    }

    public DictionaryViewModel(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        Rows = new ObservableCollection<T>(collection);
    }
}
```

usage

```
DictionaryViewModel<Person> model =
                 new DictionaryViewModel<Person>(dataContext.Persons);
```